# Assign/Convert to Adobe RGB Color profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

Is there a way I can convert an image of unknown color profile to Adobe RGB in ImageResizer, i found that by default ImageResizer assigns RGB (sRGB profile) to the compressed image.

Of what I'm aware, the client have used Adobe RGB, and CMYK — when converting from Adobe RGB the difference is barely noticeable, but when converting from CMYK, the difference is quite significant.

I've got an example here:

CMYK converted by Photoshop CS6:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcVLH.jpg

CMYK converted by Imageresizer: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd9J1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

#### ImageResizer offers multiple imaging pipelines (GDI+, WIC, FreeImage). The default pipeline (GDI+) converts all incoming color profiles to sRGB prior to processing the image, and all output images are in the sRGB color space.

If you don't like how GDI+ applies color profiles to CMYK images, you might try the [WIC pipeline](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/wic) or [FreeImage pipeline](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/freeimage).